# jquery div remove in a td issue

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a litte issue with jQuery and .remove().

I have a `td` and inside the `td` I have a `div`. When I click the `td` I want to show the `div`. When it is visible I can click the `div` and after clicking it shall be removed.

I use the following javascript code:

```
$("td").click(function () {
    $(".dragDiv").show();
});

$("#1").on("click", function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

The removing works fine but after I call .remove() I cannot click the `td` again. Nothing happens.

So what is wrong? Any help, appreciate it!!

Here is a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwurzer/kz1wmajL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.remove()` literally deletes the div. What you should use is `.hide()` or `.addClass( 'hide' );

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toggle` function, is better for reading code, and it's not complicated.

```
$('td').on('click', function() {
    $('#1').toggle();
});
```

So, when you `click` on td element (we are using `on` because jQuery in future will deprecated short hand functions) you are asking if `div#1` is showed or not. If not, hide that element.

Answer (score 1):

The click event still works on the td after you click and then after you remove the div. The problem is that the div is *removed*, as in gone. So there is nothing to show, and as that element is gone there is no longer an element with an event there.

You probably wanted hide.

```
$("#1").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Which simply sets `display:none` to hide the element as opposed to permanently removing it.

This brings up another issue with your code though, which is that the div id=1 (ids are suggested to not start with numbers), is nested inside of the td element. So when the click event on the div occurs, it also then propagates out to the td. This means that once the div is shown, it will hide, and the event will propagate to the td and show it again preventing it from hiding. This may have been your original issue and why remove seemed to work.

In order to prevent that from happening, taking the event and calling `event.stopPropagation()` is required. jQuery provides a shortcut of doing this (in addition with event.preventDefault()) by using `return false`. That would look like this:

```
$("#1").on("click", function () {
    $(this).hide();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It if your intention is to remove the element ( not hide it ), then you might wanna look into the `.detach()` function. It would remove the element from the DOM temporarily and would be available as parameter value.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>test
            <div id="1" class="dragDiv" style="height:100px; width:100px; display:none;">Test</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

var detachedEle;

$("td").click(function () {
    if(detachedEle){
     detachedEle.appendTo("tr td");   
        $(".dragDiv").hide();
        detachedEle = null;
        return;
    }
      $(".dragDiv").show();
});

$("#1").on("click", function () {
   detachedEle = $(this).detach();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kz1wmajL/2/